# Move an image file from one server to another using PHP

Tags: php

What's the best way without installing any new stuff or using a FTP to move an image from one server to another? how would you accomplish that ?

Can you use php `CURL` to take a file uploaded to a webserver and move it to a different server? Can you assign a file to `$_FILES` ?

Comment: Please show the code you've already tried, along with a description of what didn't work. Include error messages, etc

Answer (score 2):

a simple way is using `file_get_contents`

here is an example

```
$path = 'image.jpg';
$file = file_get_contents("http://yoursite.com/imagepath.jpg");
file_put_contents($path,$file);
```